# Stop auto-opening old tabs in Mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox

When I open a new window in Mozilla Firefox, other old tabs are opened automatically and downloading starts.

How do I turn this behavior off?

Comment: Do you mean when you first start Firefox, a bunch of tabs open?  Or when Firefox is running and you open the Skype tab, 5 other new tabs open?

Answer (score 0):

you can turn this feature off like this:

1. Click the <kbd>[image: menu]</kbd> button (menu) and choose <kbd>Options</kbd>
2. Select the `General` panel.
3. From the When Firefox starts drop-down, select **Show a blank page** or **Show my home page** .
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the Options window .